# How to write an Apache like access log in an hapi.js server

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am just new to hapijs and made a simple server. Now I want to have an apache like access.log written. What's the best way to do this?

Can I do this using only the hapijs server or should I better try to integrate winston to do this? If the second is preferable do you know how to integrate it.

Comment: Checkout the good reporter. It plugs in nicely and can log all requests.

Comment: I made my own plugin using winston (because i already used it in other system parts). To get a 100% compliant apache combined or custom log file I added my own formatter function to winston. That works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use the [`good`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/good) module with the [`good-apache-log`](https://github.com/jhs/good-apache-log) reporter. Here is an example how to use it:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Good = require('good');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 8080 });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('Hello, world!');
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{name}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('Hello, ' + encodeURIComponent(request.params.name) + '!');
    }
});

server.register({
    register: Good,
    options: {
        reporters: [{
            reporter: require('good-apache-log'),
            events: {
                response: '*',
                log: '*'
            },
            config: {
                path: '/var/log/hapi',
                rotate: 'daily'
            }
        }]
    }
}, function (err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err; // something bad happened loading the plugin
    }

    server.start(function () {

        server.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks good, I'll test it tomorrow. But how can I specify the line format to match an apache combined-log?

Answer (score 0):

To get something similar to an Apache access log you can use [Good](https://github.com/hapijs/good) and the [Good-File](https://github.com/hapijs/good-file) reporter and log all `response` events:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

var options = {
    reporters: [
        {
            reporter: require('good-file'),
            events: { response: '*' },
            config: 'access.log'                 // The file to log to
        }
    ]
};

server.register([
    {
        register: require('good'),
        options: options
    }
], 
function (err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.start(function (err) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log('Server started!');
    });
});
```

It will log a lot of data for each request to the file but can filter that by using the configuration options:

**Example log item for a 404 response:**

```
{
   "event":"response",
   "timestamp":1438690799059,
   "id":"1438690799059:Matts-iMac.local:12134:icxbcqzv:10000",
   "instance":"http://Matts-iMac.local:4000",
   "labels":[

   ],
   "method":"get",
   "path":"/;jkdghkjsdgf",
   "query":{

   },
   "responseTime":19,
   "statusCode":404,
   "pid":12134,
   "source":{
      "remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1",
      "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36"
   },
   "log":[
      {
         "request":"1438690799059:Matts-iMac.local:12134:icxbcqzv:10000",
         "timestamp":1438690799063,
         "tags":[
            "received"
         ],
         "data":{
            "id":"1438690799059:Matts-iMac.local:12134:icxbcqzv:10000",
            "method":"get",
            "url":"/;jkdghkjsdgf",
            "agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36"
         },
         "internal":true
      },
      {
         "request":"1438690799059:Matts-iMac.local:12134:icxbcqzv:10000",
         "timestamp":1438690799067,
         "tags":[
            "handler",
            "error"
         ],
         "data":{
            "msec":0.7662460058927536,
            "error":"Not Found",
            "data":{
               "data":null,
               "isBoom":true,
               "isServer":false,
               "output":{
                  "statusCode":404,
                  "payload":{
                     "statusCode":404,
                     "error":"Not Found"
                  },
                  "headers":{
                     "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     "cache-control":"no-cache",
                     "content-encoding":"gzip",
                     "vary":"accept-encoding"
                  }
               },
               "message":"Not Found"
            }
         },
         "internal":true
      },
      {
         "request":"1438690799059:Matts-iMac.local:12134:icxbcqzv:10000",
         "timestamp":1438690799078,
         "tags":[
            "response"
         ],
         "internal":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of information but I want to analyze the log with a classical statistic tool. That's the reason I specifically asked for an apache like log file. Such large json entries are not easy readable in vi and not analyzable in any webstats tool.